# How do I manually trigger systemd's "auto mounting" of encrypted partitions/drives?

Tags: systemd, luks, automounting

I set up two LUKS encrypted drives to automount on system startup (using `crypttab` and a LUKS file key). It works fine, but unfortunately, if I disconnect one of the drives, the "auto decrypting" process doesn't run when I connect them to my PC again (running Fedora), and I have to do the mounting manually after unmounting. What command can I use to trigger the same process that systemd triggers on system startup to auto-mount and decrypt the drives on cue without further involvement from me? Or, failing that, how can I get systemd to auto-decrypt and mount them in those circumstances?

For reference, this is the tutorial I used to set up the drives: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/mount-luks-encrypted-disk-partition-linux/

Comment: Did you cleanly unmount the drive before disconnecting it?

Comment: systemd doesn't unmount the drives if I disconnect them or they lose power for whatever reason. So no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each entry in `/etc/crypttab` is automatically converted by systemd's
`systemd-cryptsetup-generator` into a Unit at boot or when you run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`. For example, assuming the LUKS filesystem has a
UUID of `1111...` (I won't show it in full) the entry

```
mytest /dev/disk/by-uuid/1111...  /etc/luks/mykeyfile luks
```

will generate the file
`/run/systemd/generator/systemd-cryptsetup@mytest.service`, with a
dependency `BindsTo=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1111....device` and so on. This
Unit runs `cryptsetup` when the UUID appears on a new disk.

Similarly, each entry in `/etc/fstab` is automatically converted by systemd's
`systemd-fstab-generator` into a Unit. For example, the entry

```
/dev/mapper/mytest /mnt/mytest ext4 defaults
```

will generate the file
`/run/systemd/generator/mnt-mytest.mount`, which (perhaps via
udev) will do a mount whenever the file `/dev/mapper/mytest` appears (it
will be created by `cryptsetup`).

You can check the status of these two Units with

```
systemctl status systemd-cryptsetup@mytest mnt-mytest.mount
```

Normally, when the decryption and mount has been done successfully they
will show respectively as

```
   Active: active (exited)
   Active: active (mounted)
```

To remove the disk cleanly, first give the commands

```
sudo systemctl stop mnt-mytest.mount
sudo systemctl stop systemd-cryptsetup@mytest
```

When this disk is plugged in again, it will be mounted automatically.

---

If the mounted disk is removed without doing this, the Units can be left in a
failed state.
Tail the systemd logs with `journalctl -f` to see the messages.

Sometimes, on unplugging without unmounting, the kernel emits messages
about i/o errors on the filesystem, but it manages to successfully unmount
the filesystem, and the crypt detach successfully closes the device. In
this case, when the device is plugged back in it should be successfully
mounted automatically with no intervention.

However, sometimes, after the i/o errors, the kernel decides to remount the
filesystem read-only. This causes a problem for the crypt detach command,
which fails because the device is busy (mounted, when it should have been
unmounted by systemd). There seems to be a race problem as the filesystem
usually ends up unmounted. When the device is plugged back in, the
decryption says the volume is already active, so does not seem to trigger
the mount.

In this case, what seems to work is to clear the failed state of the stop
job, and to run the detach command manually. When the device is
plugged in again, the decryption mechanism starts off cleanly, and the
mount gets done. The commands are

```
sudo systemctl reset-failed systemd-cryptsetup@mytest
sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup detach mytest
```

There is also a `dev-mapper-mytest.device` unit that can be checked for status.
It remains in the active state if the detach failed, but will become
inactive after the above manual detach command.

Comment: I know I have tried `sudo systemctl *restart*` for both the mount and systemd-cryptsetup before to no avail but never did it in a particular order. I will try this and report back. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't automount the drives automatically. I had to stop and start the units again. Wasn't it supposed to do it automatically?

Comment: I found it mounted automatically, by doing stop on the 2 units, waiting until the journal log has settled down, then doing start on the 2 units again. You really need to look at the log messages to get a hint as to what errors are being provoked, at what time (unplug, replug), and also wait a few seconds each time for the log to settle. I think I saw read errors from the unplugged event re-appearing later when the device was plugged in again, but after waiting for these to go, and doing a successful stop, wait, start, it did eventually recover. Sorry, I don't have an exact solution.

Comment: By mounting automatically you mean "then doing start on the 2 units again" with the drive plugged in? Or did you stop both units, started them, and then connected the drives and they mounted automatically?

Comment: I've edited my answer, under the horizontal line. This describes the failure mode I see, and the fix. However, it may not correspond to your case, which is why you need to check the journal log for clues as to what is failing in the use you make of your device.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it works although I did expect a more straightforward answer. However, since I learned that the USB hub I was using was simply defective and that might've caused the commands to not work reliably.

Answer (score 2):

(for a related answer that covers an additional LVM layer atop LUKS see: https://serverfault.com/a/1120163/582319)

The problem is that the default mounting mechanism isn't set up for any kind of "dynamic" attaching/detaching of devices, *although* `systemd` (in concert with `udev`) provides all the machinery necessary to support such functionality...

### The Tools

`systemctl show <unit>`, `systemctl status <unit>` and `udevadm info /device/file` together with `journalctl -e` are useful/necessary to understand/verify how the units are hooked up with each other.

### The Problem

`systemctl show systemd-crptsetup@<luksvolume>.service` shows that by default the service unit that activates the `luksvolume` is only `WantedBy=` the standard `cryptsetup.target` during the system startup process, and that's it.

(BTW: I suggest always adding `noauto,nofail` as crypttab options for "dynamic" luks volumes, because we are directly taking charge of wiring up all the parts).

### A Solution

#### Hooking the service up to the underlying device via udev

What we want is to have the service unit triggered every time `udev` discovers the device being (re-)attached. This can be done via a `udev` rule like:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="your-UUID", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service"
```

located in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory, name it for example `99-usbactivation.rules`. The important thing is to use device specific environment variable and/or attribute values (query them via `udevadm info /device/name`). Keep in mind that `==` is a match while `=` (and `+=`) is an assignment.

A quirk (at least on my setup) is that `systemctl show` and even `udevadm info` often don't show the newly created `wants` relationship,  but you will know if things work if/when the `luksvolume` automagically appears in `lsblk`...

Further inspection of the `sytemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service` unit shows that it `BindsTo=` the underlying device, meaning, that the unit will automatically stop whenever the device is gone, we don't have to take any special steps in that regard.

#### Hooking the service up to the mount point via `/etc/fstab`

`fstab` mount points like `/mnt/foo` get translated by systemd into `.mount` units like `mnt-foo.mount` via a generator early on. The translated units themselves are actual files which can be found in `/run/systemd/generator/` (or simply use `systemctl cat <unit>` to display the content). All systemd units can have the same basic properties like `Before=`, `After=`, or `Requires=`, `Wants=` properties, including `.mount`, `.device`, `.target`, etc. and can be inspect via the usual `systemctl show`, etc. tools.

Any change to `/etc/fstab`, like any change to systemd unit files in general (e.g. via calling `systemctl edit <unit>` or directly editing files in `/etc/systemd/sytem/` only is picked up by systemd after calling `systemctl daemon-reload`. In the case of mount points, this will completely recreate the `/run/systemd/generator` directory and its contained files.

a relevant mount point in `/etc/fstab` will look similar to:

```
/dev/mapper/<luksvolume>    /mnt/foo    ext4    defaults    0 2
```

As the [systemd documentation for mount units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) states, this generally hooks up the unit with the necessary `BindsTo=`, `RequiresMountsFor=` and ordering `After=`, `Before=` properties sufficient for systemd emulating vanilla static/user triggered mounting and unmounting.

What we have to add is the special systemd mount properties `x-systemd.after=systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service` to ensure that the mount unit waits for cryptsetup finishing its job.

Finally, we continue the "wants chain" (my term) started by the udev rule to make the cryptsetup service "want to start" our mount unit. This is accomplished via `x-systemd.wanted-by=`, which is the fstab equivalent of the `[Install]` section element `WantedBy=<unit>`, which results in the creation of a `<unit>.wants` directory with a symlink to the mount unit file like in `/run/systemd/generator`. Because the `systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service` unit only exists to lead to the creation of a `dev-mapper-<luksvolume>.device` unit, we can also address this unit, e.g. via `x-systemd.wanted-by=dev-mapper-<luksvolume>.device`.

This all results in an `fstab` entry like:

```
/dev/mapper/<luksvolume>    /mnt/foo    ext4    defaults,x-systemd.wanted-by=dev-mapper-<luksvolume>.device,x-systemd.after=systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service    0 2
```

Everything should now "just work" and even detaching the drive should lead to an orderly shutdown of the systemd units.

#### "Unmounting"

Because all the relevant units are "wanted" by their underlying units from the "bottom-up direction" and because units lifetime is bound to the underlying unit via a "BindsTo=" relationship (either explicitly or implicitly), we can just deactivate the `systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service` via `systemctl stop` and that should be enough.

Another possibility is to create and start a custom "top down" `my_unmount@foo.target` unit whose whole purpose is to field `Conflicts=` statements with the relevant units at play, which means that if the target is started by the user, the conflicting units are stopped. This is necessary because merely deactivating e.g. the mount unit **does not** stop the cryptsetup service (we could achieve this by modifying the service unit e.g. via `sytemctl edit` and adding a `BindsTo=` property). However, because our relevant units are already well ordered among each other and running, these are guaranteed to orderly stop by starting the target unit.

Such a target unit would look like:

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=mnt-foo.mount systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service
After=mnt-foo.mount systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service
```

### Variant: directly hooking up the `.mount` unit

During my research on how to add an additional LVM layer (see again the [serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1120163/582319)), I ended up rewiring my personal (LUKS only, no LVM layer) setup to directly hook up the `.mount` unit to `udev` instead of the `systemd-cryptsetup@.service` unit. The udev rule now looks like:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="your-UUID", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="mnt-foo.mount"
```

the `/etc/crypttab` entry:

```
<luksvolume>    UUID=<uuid>    /dir/keyfile    luks,nofail,noauto
```

This allows us to get away with a normal `/etc/fstab` mount point definition, without any special `x-systemd.<opt>` mount options.

```
/dev/mapper/<luksvolume>    /mnt/foo    ext4    defaults,nofail,noauto    0 2
```

The only annoyance is that we need to append additional configuration to `systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service`, e.g. via calling `systemctl edit systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service`, which by default results in a new conf file `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvolume>.service.d/override.conf`, to which we add:

```
[Unit]
BindTo=mnt-foo.mount
Before=mnt-foo.mount
```

Now the cryptsetup service's lifetime is bound both to the underlying device unit *as well as* the lifetime of the mount point, if either the backing device vanishes *or* the mount point stops (e.g. upon user request), the service will be stopped as well (and in the correct order).

Conceptually, this approach has the advantage that the user can ignore the cryptsetup unit and just start/stop the mount point. Unfortunately, the classic `mount` command does not work for some reason (`umount` does), at least on my distro. I suggest always using `systemctl start/stop /mnt/foo` and similar, which works as expected.

Comment: In `udevadm info /device/file` what should `/device/file` be? I'm getting `Bad argument "/device/file", expected an absolute path in /dev/ or /sys or a unit name: Invalid argument` running the command as is.

Comment: Whatever "device file" you are interested in, maybe something like `/dev/sdc`, depends

Comment: Very successfully tested for me. I chose the first one (not the variant) for learning the chaining process. It's a real pleasure to just plug in an external volume and have it automatically decrypted and mounted. When finished with the device I just run `sudo systemctl stop systemd-cryptsetup@<luks-volume>` without being asked for a password (thanks to a new rule I added in the _sudoers_ file). Thank you very very much for your answer T Nierath!!!